# css class specifier before or after, no consistently?

Tags: html, css, class

I don't understand whether class should be specified before or after the tag it modifies.

The following in my stylesheet modifies the divs appropriately:

```
div.idea {
  margin: 0.1cm;
  }
```

The following does not:

```
.idea div {
      margin: 0.1cm;
}
```

Yet, the following does *not* modify my anchors:

```
a.idea {
      color: Orange;
}
```

and the following does:

```
.idea a {
      color: Orange;
}
```

Explain?

Comment: I actually did.  Sometimes documentation is inadequate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`div.idea` means a `div` with a class `idea`

`.idea div` means a `div` within an element with class `idea`

They are targeting different elements. Without seeing your HTML, it is impossible to explain why you are witnessing behavior you interpret as unusual.

Answer (score 3):

A space is very important. A space means "child" of. No space means "and".

So:

`div.idea` : A div with the class `idea`

```
<DIV class="idea"></DIV>
```

`div .idea` : A child with the class "idea" with a parent that is a div (anywhere above it)

```
<DIV>
  <DIV class="idea"></DIV>
</DIV>
```

Answer (score 2):

CSS selectors:

```
div.idea { ...  // a div that has a class="idea"
.idea div { ... // any div, that has a parent (or ancestor) that has a class="idea"
a.idea { ...    // an <a> element which has a class="idea" ( <a class="idea">text</a> )
.idea a { ..    // an <a> element which has a parent (or ancestor) of any element type (not only div) which has a class="idea"
```

consult [CSS selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html), especially [class selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#class-html)

Answer (score 2):

You do not *need* to specify any element before using a class selector - it merely adds a layer of specificity.

Your first example:

```
div.idea {
  margin: 0.1cm;
}
```

This selects first all div elements, then restricts them to elements with class `idea`.

Your second example:

```
.idea div {
      margin: 0.1cm;
}
```

Selects all elements with the class `idea`, and then selects all of the children of those elements.

The two expressions equate to different things:

`div.idea` selects divs that have the class idea
`.idea div` selects the children of `idea` elements that are divs

In effect, the space makes you select the child

Comment: I see.  I was actually wondering where css styles get inherited, and where not.  That answers that for me.

Answer (score 1):

You css selectors assume the following

> div.idea {margin: 0.1cm;}

```
<div class="idea" id="iGetStyled">...
```

> .idea div {margin: 0.1cm;}

```
<div class="idea"><div id="iGetStyled">...
```

> a.idea {color: Orange;}

```
<a class="idea" id="iGetStyled">...
```

> .idea a {color: Orange;}

```
<div class="idea"><a id="iGetStyled">...
```

`id="iGetStyled"` shows you which items will be styled